# how to use session without having to pass it [SqlAlchemy]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to check diferent values in the DB and create a new value, so i need to query and i don't know if i have to create a session in my SQLAlchemy class or how do i have to do it? using session like a global?, i didn't find in documentation.

Somethin like this:

```
class MyClass(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'my_class'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('key', 'key2'),
                     {}
                     )
    id =  Column(Integer, Sequence('my_class_id'), primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String(30), nullable= False) #unique together key2
    key2 = Column(String(30), nullable = False) 
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, key, key2):
        #check if exist key and key2
        values = session.query(MyClass.value).filter(MyClass.key == self.key).\
            filter(MyClass.key2 == self)

        if values:
            raise IntegrityError

        #get biggest value
        value = session.query(MyClass.value).filter(MyClass.key = self.key).order_by(asc(MyClass.value)) #I'm not shure if i need 'asc'
        #no value new key and key2

        if not value:
            self.key = key
            self.key2 = key2
            self.value = '000'
            return

        #i used a single table beacuse is easier to understand
        #in this example
        self.key = key
        self.key2 = key
        self.value = increment(value.first())
```

I'm using SQLALchemy 6.2 and declarative

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this better handled in the database, using unique indexes?

Comment: it will be easier, but any way i would like to learn how to do it, but i saw that is not so easier like django DRM, any way i can't do it on __init__ because it has to be binded to some session

Comment: and anyway the value will be used a lot, and it has to be compact, thats the reason beacause i'm using a string to do something like '1Za'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do your own session management -- e.g. define a module-global session object.

For example, Pylons applications define their session like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
```

and then later bind it to an engine with

```
Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

Using scoped_session will mean that your code is thread-safe (each thread will use its own session).

Answer (score 1):

I  found [here](http://www.python-blog.com/2009/10/21/sqlalchemy-give-me-my-session-object/) that  we can do **Session.object_session(self)**:

```
def new_value(self):
    #not really DRY
    #the object has to be binded with some session first.
    session = Session.object_session(self) # << this is the important stuff

    #check if exist key and key2
    values = session.query(MyClass.value).filter(MyClass.key == self.key).\
        filter(MyClass.key2 == self)

    if values:
        return #None

    #get biggest value
    value = session.query(MyClass.value).\
               filter(MyClass.key = self.key).\
               order_by(desc(MyClass.value))

    return increment(value.first())
```

Comment: This will not work for newly-created objects that haven't been added to a session, though.  And since you're trying to use it from a constructor, this would mean you cannot create new objects at all.

Comment: in fact i changed this part of code inside of a MapperExtension, inside of before_insert, i'll update my code